# Dataset about the kinds of scientific experiments published

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset that has information about the categories of scientific experiments performed for a given year.

I assume this may be information contained in abstract metadata, but I'm not sure where to get this dataset either.

Comment: Worldwide, **all** sciences, free, what format? https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like